# tf2_eigen include does not find library Eigen/Geometry

Tags: geometry, eigen, include, ros-kinetic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use `tf2_eigen` to convert `geometry_msgs/Vector3` messages (and further `geometry_msgs`) to eigen-vectors to use them for calculations.

The preprocessor does not find this include in tf2_eigen:  `#include <Eigen/Geometry>`

I deem the reason for this is that eigen3 is installed on my computer and the path should be: `<eigen3/Eigen/Geometry>`

Do you have an idea how I can handle this problem? I have no permission to change the `tf2_eigen` file.

Additionaly my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(px4_data_observer)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  message_filters
  geometry_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  eigen_conversions
  tf2
  tf2_eigen
)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
catkin_package(
)
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Thank you in advanced!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309581/tf2_eigen-include-does-not-find-library-eigen/geometry/) by [teflon](https://answers.ros.org/users/38711/teflon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I include now Eigen3 and fixed a misstake I did in my code. I used the wrong namespace. Instead of the correct tf2::fromMsg () I used Eigen::fromMsg() because the autocomplition suggests this. My preprocessor still does not find the Eigen/Geometry include but building works. Also the function tf2::fromMsg() works now :) Thank you very much for the hint!

---

Originally posted by [teflon](https://answers.ros.org/users/38711/teflon/) with karma: 16 on 2018-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0